How can I stop my count if the timer hits 00:00?
I am currently programing an app as a project. While doing so I just got into Javascript yesterday and I am having an issue to stop my count.
What is my program doing:
You can see an image, which you have to click on. With every click the count gets +1. While doing so, a time of 30sec is running down and showing on the screen as well.
What do I want to reach:
I got everything working so far. The timer is working perfectly, the count is working while I am clicking on the image. But what I can't get to work is that the image should not be click-able anymore after the timer hits 00:00 and the count should stay at the last reached number, so I can put it into a highscore list.
It's especially about this part:
function blobPress() {
            if (timeLeft > 0) {
                count++;
                document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
            } else {
                blob.style.display = "block";
            }
        }



let alarm = new Audio('alarm.mp3');
let finish = new Audio('finish.mp3');
let timerStarted = false;
let count = 0;


function startTimer() {
  if (!timerStarted) {
    let startTime = new Date().getTime();
    let thirtySeconds = 1000 * 30;
    let endTime = startTime + thirtySeconds;
    alarm.play();


    let refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
      let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();


      if (timeLeft > 0) {
        let minutes = timeLeft / (1000 * 60);
        minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
        let seconds = (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
        seconds = Math.round(seconds);
        seconds = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);
        let text = '0'  +  minutes  +  ' : '  +  seconds;
        timer.innerHTML = text;
      } else {
        finish.play();
        timer.innerHTML = '00 : 00';
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
      }
    }, 1000);
    timerStarted = true;
  }
}

function showCount() {
  if (timerStarted) {
    document.getElementById('count').style.color = "white";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('count').style.color = "#262626";
  }
}

function hideButton() {
  if (button.style.display === "none") {
    button.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function blobPress() {
  if (timeLeft > 0) {
    count++;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
  } else {
    blob.style.display = "block";
  }
}
body {background-color: #262626;} 

.background-dark {
  background-color: #262626;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.count {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #262626;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
<div>
  <img src="img/menu.png">
</div>


<div class="center margin-top count" id="count">0</div>


<div class="center margin-top">
  <img id="blob" onclick="blobPress()" src="img/blob.png" style="transform: scale(0.9);">
</div>


<div class="center margin-top timer" id="timer">00 : 30</div>


<div class="center margin-top">
  <img id="button" onclick="startTimer(); showCount(); hideButton()" src="img/button.png" style="transform: scale(0.8);">
</div>




@mplungjan let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();

When I remove the if-function around my count++ statement it works totally fine. But I can still click on the image and the count gets higher. I don't know how to tell my program that it should stop counting if the timer hits 00:00.

You need to move the let timeLeft outside the function since you need it in blobPress where it is currently out of scope

Clicking the button does not count up when the timer is done

I do recommend to use addEventListener instead of using inline onclick

I tried using addEventListener before but it's not working at all. Also it won't make sense in the program for me, since many onclicks have to be overwritten.

function blobPress() {             if (timeLeft > 0) {                 count++;                 document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;             } else {                 blob.style.display = "block";             }         } This function is a test since I can't get it to work. Remove everything inside the function ecxept for "count++, document.get.......". The count when clicking on the image works then, but it will still work with the timer at 00:00, which I don't want to have.

Your code does not work right now at all. You must remove the let from let timeLeft = and add let timeLeft; to just after let count = 0; If you do that, the code works as expected, including the click to increment or not

The issues were:

timeLeft was not defined inside blobPress().
count was not handled correctly.

I fixed the issues by doing the following changes:

Removed onclick from #blob.
Created a click event listener for the blob.
Passed timeLeft to blobPress(timeLeft).
Created a function parseTimeToSeconds(timeStr) to return timeLeft in integer as when you get it by innerHTML, it returns string.

I also added alt attributes to the images. Rest of your code is untouched.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .background-dark {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .center {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .margin-top {
        margin-top: 60px;
      }

      .timer {
        font-size: 80px;
        color: white;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      }

      .count {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #262626;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="img/menu.png" alt="Menu Img" />
    </div>

    <div class="center margin-top count" id="count">0</div>

    <div class="center margin-top">
      <img
        id="blob"
        src="img/blob.png"
        style="transform: scale(0.9)"
        alt="Blob Img"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="center margin-top timer" id="timer">00 : 30</div>

    <div class="center margin-top">
      <img
        id="button"
        onclick="startTimer(); showCount(); hideButton()"
        src="img/button.png"
        style="transform: scale(0.8)"
        alt="Button Img"
      />
    </div>

    <script>
      let alarm = new Audio("alarm.mp3");
      let finish = new Audio("finish.mp3");
      let timerStarted = false;
      let count = 0;

      function startTimer() {
        if (!timerStarted) {
          let startTime = new Date().getTime();
          let thirtySeconds = 1000 * 30;
          let endTime = startTime + thirtySeconds;
          alarm.play();

          let refreshInterval = setInterval(function () {
            let timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime();

            if (timeLeft > 0) {
              let minutes = timeLeft / (1000 * 60);
              minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
              let seconds = (timeLeft / 1000) % 60;
              seconds = Math.round(seconds);
              seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
              let text = "0" + minutes + " : " + seconds;
              timer.innerHTML = text;
            } else {
              finish.play();
              timer.innerHTML = "00 : 00";
              clearInterval(refreshInterval);
            }
          }, 1000);
          timerStarted = true;
        }
      }

      function showCount() {
        if (timerStarted) {
          document.getElementById("count").style.color = "white";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("count").style.color = "#262626";
        }
      }

      function hideButton() {
        if (button.style.display === "none") {
          button.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          button.style.display = "none";
        }
      }

      let blobBtn = document.getElementById("blob");

      blobBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let timeLeft = document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML;

        // console.log("Time left: " + timeLeft);

        blobPress(timeLeft);
      });

      function blobPress(timeLeft) {
        let countElement = document.getElementById("count");
        let count = parseInt(countElement.innerHTML);

        // console.log("Count: " + count);

        let remainingTime = parseTimeToSeconds(timeLeft);

        if (remainingTime > 0) {
          count++;
          countElement.innerHTML = count;
        } else {
          blob.style.display = "block";
        }
      }

      function parseTimeToSeconds(timeStr) {
        let timeParts = timeStr.split(" : ");
        let minutes = parseInt(timeParts[0]);
        let seconds = parseInt(timeParts[1]);

        return minutes * 60 + seconds;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


It is generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers. Use addEventListener to handle events within the scripting.
Muhammad Aleem Hashmi already explained the issues with your code.
I took the liberty to create a timer factory. Maybe its useful for your project.
To demonstrate its use here is a minimal reproducable example based on your code. The handling uses event delegation.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
const myTimer = timerFactory(document.querySelector(`#timer`));

// a factory to show a timer (counting backwards) in [timerDiv]
function timerFactory(timerDiv) {
  let start, running;

  return function(seconds) {
    if (!running) {
      start = new Date();
      running = true;
      runTimer(seconds);
    }
  };

  function runTimer(seconds) {
    if (seconds >= 0) {
      const [min, sec] = diff(seconds);
      timerDiv.textContent = `${min} : ${sec}`;
      return setTimeout(_ => runTimer(seconds - 1), 1000);
    }

    running = false;
  }

  function diff(secondsLeft) {
    const end = new Date(start);
    const diff = new Date(
      end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() + secondsLeft) - start );
    return [
      `${diff.getUTCMinutes()}`.padStart(2, `0`),
      `${diff.getUTCSeconds()}`.padStart(2, `0`)];
  }
}

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `startTimer`) {
    console.clear();
    return handleTimer();
  }
}

function handleTimer() {
  const inp = document.querySelector(`#nSeconds`);
  const seconds = +inp.value;

  if (seconds < +inp.min || seconds > inp.max) {
    return console.log(`${seconds} seconds not within limits (${
        inp.min} - ${inp.max} seconds)`);
  };

  return myTimer(seconds);
}
body {
  background-color: #262626;
}

input#nSeconds {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}

#startTimer {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  span.white {
    color: white
  }
}

.timer {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
<div class="center margin-top timer" id="timer">00 : 00</div>
<div class="center">
  <input type="number" value="10" min="5" max="120" id="nSeconds">
  <span class="white">seconds</span>
  <button id="startTimer">start timer</button>
</div>



